# Deserializing JSON into a List (or other object type)

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, deserialization

I am having issues deserializing some `JSON` into an object type that I can work with.

I have been playing around with multiple different ways to deserialize something, but I cannot get any of them to work.  I am trying, currently, to use the `Newtonsoft.Json` deserializer.

```
Public Class ServerRecord
    Inherits Record
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("sys_class_name")>
    Public Property sys_class_name As String
        Get
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
        End Set
    End Property

    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("host_name")>
    Public Property host_name As String
        Get
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
        End Set
    End Property
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("u_recovery_time_achievable")>
    Public Property u_recovery_time_achievable As String
        Get
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class


Dim lstSNServersList As New List(Of ServerRecord)
Dim objServiceNowTableAPIClient As TableAPI.TableAPIClient(Of ServerRecord)
Dim objServiceNowRESTQueryResponse As RESTQueryResponse(Of ServerRecord)

    objServiceNowTableAPIClient = New TableAPIClient(Of wServerRecord)(strServiceNowCMDBServersTableName, strServiceNowInstanceName, strServiceNowUser, strServiceNowPassword)
    strServiceNowQuery = "sys_class_name=cmdb_ci_win_server^ORsys_class_name=cmdb_ci_linux_server"
    objServiceNowRESTQueryResponse = objServiceNowTableAPIClient.GetByQuery(strServiceNowQuery)
    'this much does work and it does return a result set

    'this is my attempt to convert this response into a list of ServerRecords, but this does not work currently:
    lstSNServersList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of ServerRecord))(objServiceNowRESTQueryResponse.RawJSON)
```

The `objServiceNowRestQueryResponse.RawJSON` string looks like this (though much longer):

```
{
   "result":[
      {
         "sys_id":"00040665dbxxxxxx96191e",
         "u_recovery_time_achievable":"720",
         "sys_class_name":"cmdb_ci_linux_server",
         "host_name":"rlserver001"
      },
      {
         "sys_id":"00ec543d1xxxx66e4bcb6d",
         "u_recovery_time_achievable":"4",
         "sys_class_name":"cmdb_ci_linux_server",
         "host_name":"plserver001"
      },
      {
         "sys_id":"0105d975dbxxxxx8961998",
         "u_recovery_time_achievable":"",
         "sys_class_name":"cmdb_ci_linux_server",
         "host_name":"tlserver001"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is the error message I get when trying to run my code:

> Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in
> Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
> (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CMDBReconciliation.CMDBReconciliation+ServiceNowServerRecord]'
> because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
> [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
> type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
> like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
> JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
> deserialize from a JSON object.
>
> Path 'result', line 1, position 10.

Comment: The json itself is not a list I think, because you also have the "result"  element in there. Because of that, I think you need to have a "result" class with a property that is a list of ServerRecord. Does that make sense?

Comment: You could deserialize to a `RootObject` class which has a `List(Of ServerRecord)` property type, to a DataTable as in `Dim jsonObject = JObject.Parse("[Your JSON]")) Dim myDTResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(jsonObject("result").ToString())` and many other ways.

Comment: Use Auto properties, as `<JsonProperty("sys_class_name")> Public Property SysClassName As String` etc.

Comment: That is perfect!  Thanks Jimi (and Alex too)!  The below works and I'm able to loop through all the entries now!!
                    Dim jsonObject = JObject.Parse(objServiceNowRESTQueryResponse.RawJSON)
                    Dim myDTResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(jsonObject("result").ToString())
                    For Each row As DataRow In myDTResults.Rows
                        ServerName = row("host_name")
                    Next

Answer (score 0):

This will work. It just extracts the array part from the json string.

```
Dim start As Integer = objServiceNowRESTQueryResponse.IndexOf("[")
Dim last As Integer = objServiceNowRESTQueryResponse.LastIndexOf("]")
lstSNServersList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of ServerRecord))(objServiceNowRESTQueryResponse.Substring(start, last - start + 1))
```